How can I prevent GitHub Actions YAML file from being deployed?
I have a .github/workflows/deploy.yaml file for working with GitHub Actions. Now I need to delete that workflow but I don't want to delete YAML file in case I need that.
Is there anything like 'status:false' attribute or something like that?

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow?tool=cli

...or just move it? For that matter you could delete it and get it back from version control, which if you're using GitHub you must already be using, if needed.

You can also use if: false at the job level. Additionally, the file's not gone if you delete it, you can always get it back from Git?

I'm aware checking git version history, just was thinking it should be very easy but cant find it easliy...

I'm not sure what you mean by "it", but if it is "retrieving a file from Git history", it's something like git restore --source <commit_sha> .github/workflows/deploy.yaml

I mean disabling from yaml file. so adding "if:false" is nice answer which offered from friends.

Options:

Disabling the workflow


Using the UI: Actions > WORKFLOW > ... > Disable workflow

Using the GitHub CLI: gh workflow disable WORKFLOW
See more info at GitHub documentation here



Using "if" conditional


Add an "if: false" to the job.
See more info at GitHub documentation here



Moving the workflow


Move the deploy.yaml from .github/workflow to any other directory.

